# How to find public key for adding new user to EC2 instance running Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to add an additional user to an EC2 instance running Ubuntu so they can do some development work for me. I have been following the Amazon instructions here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html but I get stuck on step 2 (f):

> "f. Edit the authorized_keys file with your favorite text editor and paste the public key for your key pair into the file".

Where can I find "the public key for your key pair into the file"?

Comment: Typical... after struggling for hours to find a solution, within minutes of posting here I solve it. Murphy's Law strikes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here for anyone interested:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#retrieving-the-public-key

It's a little cryptic for newbies, but here's what I did:

1. upload the PEM file to directory I could access after I "sudo su" as the new user
2. run "sudo su newuser"
3. run "ssh-keygen -y"
4. enter the path of the PEM file I uploaded in step #1
5. copy the output from the script
6. open the /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys file using favorite text editor
7. delete any existing text
8. paste the content the was copied in #5 above
9. save file

I was then able to connect using PuTTY and all is good in the world again.

Comment: Thanks @halfer. Seemed a little weird giving myself a tick, but here goes... :)